# Can't call event from button

Tags: c#, winforms, events

I have three different events:

```
form_load
button_click
pnlTiles_Paint
```

My button click event I have:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlTiles.Paint += pnlTiles_Paint;
}
```

My form_load event I have:

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlTiles.Paint += pnlTiles_Paint;
}
```

Now my problem is that the event gets called when I use it in form_load but when I use it in the button event; it just skips over the event, I tried to step into the event when debugging the button click. But I made no progress on trying to figure out why the event doesn't get called from the button.

Comment: Those statements don't *call* an event - they *subscribe* to an event. That's very different.

Comment: So your handlers will only get called when that `Paint` event you're subscribing to is fired.

Comment: Re: `"I have three different events"` - No, you have three different event *handlers*.

Comment: Yes, you should better make a separate function with the code in Paint and then call that function from the Load and Click events, if possible. In your code, you actually subscribe the Paint event of the Panel to pnlTiles_Paint. And I think that the Paint event is fired when the form paints itself (the panel has to paint itself too).

Comment: This doesn't explain why it works in the load event and not the button event though

Comment: @user2836518 it doesn't work in the load event either. Step through, you will not see the pnlTiles_Paint function running until after the form is shown, and the paint event is fired.

Comment: @user2836518 you are re-subscribing to the .Paint event in the button that does not call the method pnlTiles_Paint().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `pnlTiles.Paint += pnlTiles_Paint;` means you are subscribing to the `Paint` event on the control `pnlTiles`. What this means is that every time `pnlTiles` raises the `Paint` event, the method specified by `pnlTiles_Paint` will get called. What causes `Paint` to get fired? According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx),

> The Paint event is raised when the control is redrawn. It passes an instance of PaintEventArgs to the method(s) that handles the Paint event.

So what's probably happening is that `pnlTiles` raises the `Paint` event AFTER the main form raises the `Load` event (since this is the first time `pnlTiles` is getting drawn on the screen) which is why your handler ends up getting called.

However, clicking on a button does not cause `pnlTiles` to get redrawn and the `Paint` event to get raised, hence your handler does not get called.

If for some reason, after you have hooked up your handler in the `Button's` click handler, `pnlTiles` needs to be redrawn, `pnlTiles_Paint` will get called. You can test this by calling [`pnlTiles.Invalidate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) in the `Button's` click handler after subscribing to `pnlTile's` `Paint` event.

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pnlTiles.Paint += pnlTiles_Paint;
    pnlTiles.Invalidate();
}
```

Since you're a little fuzzy on the basics of events, it might be worth reading these articles:

[Jon Skeet - Events](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx)

[MSDN - Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t.aspx).

Also, make sure to read cgijbels comment on this post about not subscribing to the same event multiple times.

Comment: Don't subscribe the `pnlTiles_Paint` method to the `Paint` event in the `btnUpdate_Click` method, because each time you click on the button you'll add __another__ subscription to the `Paint` event, it doesn't matter whether it's the same method or not and your `pnlTiles_Paint` method will run several times during the same `Paint` event, slowing things down the more you click on the button. So only subscribe once, or if you really need to subscribe when clicking the button, then at least unsubscribe before subscribing again.

Comment: Sure, that's good advice. I was merely answering the question about some specific behavior so I did not consider it important to talk about the do's and dont's of subscribing to events.